# How to declare that the WCF service is using mandatory SOAP headers?

Tags: wcf, soap, soapheader

I have a WCF service which uses some custom SOAP headers.
I manage to pass the headers - but how can I declare that they are mandatory thus forcing the client to pass them in every request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a code which will validate presence of headers on your side. You also need a code which will add your custom headers to WSDL so that all clients know about this headers.

Both parts can be achievable by `MessageContract` where you will define headers and body. If you use single contract as base for all your messages it should work but you will have to validate headers in each operation.

You can also move code related to headers to custom behavior and add / validate headers in custom message inspector. In this case you must also manually add header's description to WSDL. [This blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/skaufman/archive/2009/05/29/exposing-custom-wcf-headers-through-wcf-behaviors.aspx) describes the whole process.

Comment: MessageContract is good but limits my APIs freedoms since only one parameter is allowed and I will need to make a custom class for each API (since they all have different signatures). Your other suggestion is what i do now only it does not give the client any indication that the service needs the SOAP headers.

Comment: Your last link looks like the last thing to do - so unless i will receive an answer that solves this issue in a more robust and elegant way, I will invest the time in that blog you mentioned

Comment: MessageContract doesn't limit API's to single parameter. It only wraps all parameters in single class. You will get client indication if your headers will be part of WSDL. You always have to validate on your side that headers were passed because you cannot ensure that client send them.

Comment: You are correct off-course, I meant to say that it is not convinient if all my API's have different signatures but all have to receive the same SOAP headers. in this case i have to Create custom class for each API